# RaspberryPI 4, Gpio module, malloc() : corrupted top size

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

Hello Everyone reading,

So my issue is that I have tried running the **NodeJS** on my **Raspberry Pi 4** script that has been posted on the **W3School site**, which was supposed to flash a LED light, here it is below :

```
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio; //include onoff to interact with the GPIO
var LED = new Gpio(4, 'out'); //use GPIO pin 4, and specify that it is output
var blinkInterval = setInterval(blinkLED, 250); //run the blinkLED function every 250ms

function blinkLED() { //function to start blinking
  if (LED.readSync() === 0) { //check the pin state, if the state is 0 (or off)
    LED.writeSync(1); //set pin state to 1 (turn LED on)
  } else {
    LED.writeSync(0); //set pin state to 0 (turn LED off)
  }
}

function endBlink() { //function to stop blinking
  clearInterval(blinkInterval); // Stop blink intervals
  LED.writeSync(0); // Turn LED off
  LED.unexport(); // Unexport GPIO to free resources
}

setTimeout(endBlink, 5000); //stop blinking after 5 seconds
```

*However*, as I am trying to do so, I keep on getting an error :

```
malloc() :  corrupted top size
```

I tried removing everything but even the first line kept on throwing that error.

Since I am new to RaspberryPI, I am not sure where to look for an answer since I could not find it on the internet, think it might be useful for future kids. Thank you for the help.

Comment: something may be up with your nodejs.  check that it can run something else.

Comment: I am seeing the same.  Raspberry Pi 4B, node v16.10.0

Answer (score 0):

Go to the carpet "onoff" and then update the carpet with the command "npm i"
I've just done that and the led turned on. Good luck man